# Inline function to restrict input to a number with up to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, validation, input, onkeyup

I have an input in my form currently that I am restricting to number entry only, it doesn't allow the entry of any characters other than whole numbers:

```html
<input class="quantity" type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

I would like to modify this `onkeyup` code so that it will also allow a number with up to 2 decimal places. Is it possible to do directly within the inline `onkeyup` function or will I need to create a function outside of the input and call it? I found some similar questions, but they mostly had to do with validating the input after the fact, whereas I want to restrict people from even entering something that is not a whole number or number with 1 or 2 decimal places.

Unfortunately, HTML5 patterns are not an option here either, as I have to support browsers that do not support that.

Comment: Why are you using `return null`? bu returning `false` the event will be suppressed and anything other than false will not restrict user.

Comment: @FaridRn You can see in the example that it does restrict the user.

Comment: Check my answer, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

`onkeyup` event fires after key is pressed and value has been added to the input, so you have to restrict user before value change.

Using `type="number"` user wont be able to enter any characters other than decimal numbers; and by using `min` and `max` attributes, browser will mark the input as `invalid` but this doesn't restrict user to enter values larger than max either.

In the following example I check the entered value before input's change by using `onkeypress` event listener and I check the sum of current value and newly entered value to make sure it's smaller than 100 and wont let user to enter any value that is larger than 99.

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return (this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.which) > 99) ? false : true;" min="0" max="99">
```

Link to the live example: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/faridv/kfor5x5o/10/)